# Is it appropriate to use t-tests to find the most different outcomes?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I have a large CSV file of spending by individuals on different drugs. I want to find the drugs with the most different spending patterns by gender.

The file looks a bit like this, but with 7.5k rows and 2k columns:

```
id,     gender, spending_drug_a,  spending_drug_b, spending_drug_c ... 
345089, m,      304.9,            405.2,          117.0
609235, f,      285.9,            0.45,           89.9,
345089, m,      304.9,            405.2,          112.1
609235, f,      285.9,            8.43,           89.9
```

About 6.5k of the rows are male and around 1k are female.

My question is: **what approach can I sensibly use to find the drugs with the most distinct spending patterns**? My immediate thought is

- for each column, create the null hypothesis that the two means are equal, then perform a t-test on each column
- look at the value of p for each column, and rank the lowest values first

Does this sound like a reasonable way to proceed?

I don't know if the spending distributions are typically normal, but let me know if that would be useful information.

Comment: The simple answer is: no. You can use p-values to seek answer to the question: is there a difference, while you are interested in strength of this difference - it's a different question! Also, "most distinct spending patterns" does not sound at all like "difference between means" - are you sure that this approach answers your question at all..?

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Basically I want to find the drugs where women spend the most and men spend the least (or vice versa), so I guess that does mean difference between means. Any suggestions what should I use instead of p-values to find the strength of the difference?

Comment: Would you be interested in finding a situation where half the women spend zero and half spend about 600, while all the men spend around 300? (that is, where the means are the same but the pattern is very different)... Or is it only differences in mean that matter?

Comment: @Glen_b - thanks for putting it so clearly! I'm not expecting to see any significant differences in spending pattern, so my *primary interest* is in the differences in mean. However - it would also be interesting to know how to test for differences in spending pattern, as in your example.

Comment: I'd be pretty sure the amounts would be non-normal, likely right skew and probably heteroskedastic. More importantly, are there lots of zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're primarily interested in detecting changes in typical expenditure, and drugs tend to cost different amounts; I'd imagine something like ratios might be more relevant than differences (suggesting looking for differences in a model with log link), but any zeros would have to be treated separately; this suggests considering a zero-inflated model, perhaps something like a zero-inflated gamma or zero-inflated lognormal.

--

If you want to find which particular ones are different:

One possibility is to construct some measure of difference and perform a permutation test or randomization test. Your first interest in in the mean, so one can readily compute the sample mean for groups of interest and look at differences or ratios of those. Being nonparametric, as long as the distributions would be the same *under the null*, there's no issue about what the distribution shape actually is.

One could as easily use a more general measure for the difference in distribution, like a *Kolmogorov-Smirnov*, *Cramer-von Mises* or *Anderson-Darling*-type two-sample statistic and again use a permutation-type test.

---

If you really want to identify the ones that are *most* different, that would not involve hypothesis testing, but some measure of effect-size. Confidence intervals for (say) the mean differences might be useful supplementary information. One might use bootstrap intervals for those.

Comment: Partly it will depend on how zeros figure into how you measure how distinct the distributions of spending are